# cakePHP model associations lost after model imported into controller

Tags: cakephp, recursion, model, import, controller

Due to a client's desire to have URLs that defy Cake logic I have decided to use the pages_controller.php copied from cake/libs to organize my app.
Most of the site's functionality occurs from one url making calls with ajax to different controllers so I chose Pages as the home base.

Pages has no model but I still need to access some of the relevant models so I import them.

I have tried all three methods:

```
$this->loadModel('Inventories'); 
----
$Inventories =& ClassRegistry::init('Inventories'); 
----
App::import('Controller', 'Inventories');
$Inventories = new InventoriesController;
```

The Inventories Model seems to load fine with each but when I find some records:

```
$(...)->find("all", array(
    'conditions' => array('id' => '1'),
    'recursive'=>2)
);
```

I only get results as if recursive had been set to -1 or as if there were no associated models.
This happens no matter what I set recursive to.
When I load the model in another controller I get the appropriate recursive response.

Any ideas how i can get full access to a model from pages_controller.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A messy but instant solution would be to simply populate the `$uses` array in your controller:

```
var $uses = array('Inventories', 'User'); // or whatever models need to be loaded
```

This is considered poor practice and could quickly spiral out of control, however. Mostly handy for quick testing.

You could place the functionality in appropriately named controllers, and then route your client's desired URLs to the corresponding controller / action:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/945/Routes-Configuration

**A little-known controller method (it's not in the cookbook, only the API) called `setAction()` might be the solution for you.** See:

http://api13.cakephp.org/class/controller#method-ControllersetAction

also in Cake 2.0

http://api20.cakephp.org/class/controller#method-ControllersetAction

Comment: Yes, using $uses is the proper way. This is the recommended way, not poor practice! It is a poor practice though to create fat controllers that use a gadzillion models and components. Each controller should have a clearly defined purpose, a clear and short action and nothing will spiral out of control.

Comment: @Sibidiba - if you read the OP's description of the problem, he's using the Pages controller expressly for its router ability to display whatever url his client wishes, meaning he's using it as a mega-controller that accesses numerous models. This is a tricky situation to deal with in Cake, and although $uses works and will solve his problem at least for now, see http://book.cakephp.org/view/961/components-helpers-and-uses.